# Problema al ingresar caracteres con funcion fgets

Tags: c

Estoy haciendo un programa sencillo presentando funciones básicas con C, utilizo fgets para ingresar frases con saltos de linea, pero al ejecutar, se salta la parte donde debería ingresar los datos y me imprime todo sin haber pedido los datos, adjunto codigo.

```
    #include<stdio.h>

int main(){
    int a = 10, d;
    float b = 15.15;
    char c = 'e';
    char y[50];
    char x[50]; /*Al ser char, un arreglo de caracteres, podemos definir la cantidad
    de caracteres para cada variable*/

    printf("%i,%.2f,%c\n",a,b,c);/*Salida de datos*/
    printf("Digite el valor de la variable:\n");/*Entrada de datos*/
    scanf("%i",&d);
    printf("%i\n",d);
    printf("Digite su nombre:");
    scanf("%s",x);
    printf("Su nombre es: %s\n", x);
    printf("Digite su nombre con apellidos\n");
    fgets(y,50,stdin);
    printf("Su nombre con apellidos es: %c",y);
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tu problema **no** está en `fgets( )`, sino en lo que haces justo antes: `scanf( )`.

- `fgets( )` lee hasta un salto de línea ... **y lo consume**; lo *quita* del *stream* de entrada.
- `scanf( )` **no** consume los saltos de línea, sino que los deja en el *stream* de entrada.

Pues ya lo tenemos:

```
scanf( "%s", x ); // <- Deja el \n
...
fgets( y, 50, stdin ); // <- Lee hasta un salto de línea ... que ya esta ahí.
```

Localizado el problema, la solución llega sola: llama a `fgets( )` **2 veces**:

```
  ...
  scanf( "%s", x );
  printf( "Su nombre es: %s\n", x );
  printf( "Digite su nombre con apellidos\n" );
  fgets( y, 50, stdin );
  fgets( y, 50, stdin );
  printf( "Su nombre con apellidos es: %s", y ); // <- %s, NO %c

  return 0;
}
```

Una consecuencia de esto es que en la llamada a `scanf( )` anterior, ahora puedes introducir espacios: `scanf( )` **dejará** de leer al llegar a uno, pero tu nueva llamada a `fgets( )` **descartará** todo lo que hubiera en el *stream* hasta el final de la línea introducida con anterioridad.